# Multiple (14) countdowns on HTML page don't work

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, countdown

I want to display 14 countdowns (preferably as plain `p` elements in my HTML document) on a single HTML page. I don't know anything about JavaScript so I took a countdown script from w3schools. Works fine, somehow I even manages to display the timer double digit by searching the web how to.

Here's the code (UPDATE!):

```
// defining countDownDates as an empty array : 
    var countDownDates = [];

    // adding any count down date to your array : 
    countDownDates.push(new Date("Oct 22, 2017 14:00:00").getTime());
    countDownDates.push(new Date("Oct 23, 2017 14:00:00").getTime());
    countDownDates.push(new Date("Oct 24, 2017 08:00:00").getTime());
    countDownDates.push(new Date("Oct 25, 2017 08:00:00").getTime());
    countDownDates.push(new Date("Oct 24, 2017 08:00:00").getTime());
    countDownDates.push(new Date("Oct 25, 2017 08:00:00").getTime());
    countDownDates.push(new Date("Oct 26, 2017 02:00:00").getTime());
    countDownDates.push(new Date("Oct 27, 2017 02:00:00").getTime());
    countDownDates.push(new Date("Oct 27, 2017 20:00:00").getTime());
    countDownDates.push(new Date("Oct 29, 2017 02:00:00").getTime());
    countDownDates.push(new Date("Oct 27, 2017 20:00:00").getTime());
    countDownDates.push(new Date("Oct 29, 2017 02:00:00").getTime());
    countDownDates.push(new Date("Oct 29, 2017 19:00:00").getTime());
    countDownDates.push(new Date("Oct 30, 2017 19:00:00").getTime());

    // calling an init function that will build the HTML needed for every count down
    init(countDownDates);

    // looping through your array of countDownDates
    for (var i=0;i<countDownDates.length;i++) {
        // calling the countdown function, pass it the array and the current version of i as parameters 
        countDown(countDownDates, i);
    }

    /* adds, to the document, a p element for each entry in the countDownDates array */
    function init(countDownDates) {     
        var timersDiv = document.getElementById("timers");
        var dateElement;
        for (var i=0;i<countDownDates.length;i++) {         
            dateElement = document.createElement("p");
            dateElement.id = "date" + i;
            timersDiv.appendChild(dateElement);
        }   
    }       

    /* countDown function, your countDown handling code within a reusable function */
    function countDown(countDownDates, index) {
        var x = setInterval(function() {
            var now, distance, days, hours, minutes, seconds, x;

            now = new Date().getTime();
            distance = countDownDates[index] - now;

            // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
            days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) /
            (1000 * 60 * 60));
            minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);                            

            // Display days, hours, minutes and seconds in 2 digits if < 10
            if((days+"").length === 1){
                days = "0"+days;
            }
            if((hours+"").length === 1){
                hours = "0"+hours;
            }
            if((minutes+"").length === 1){
                minutes = "0"+minutes;
            }
            if((seconds+"").length === 1){
                seconds = "0"+seconds;
            }

            // Display the result in the element with id date0, date1, etc.
            document.getElementById("date" + index).innerHTML = days + ":" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "";

            // If the count down is finished, write some text and add css class to change ended timers color 
            if (distance < 0) {
                clearInterval(x);
                document.getElementById("date" + index).className = "timerend";
                document.getElementById("date" + index).innerHTML = "00:00:00:00";
            }

        }, 1000);
    }
```

I tried to multiply the script completely 14 times with altered first line of code to a specific future date - so the same countdown shows up 14 times.

Is there a way to multiply the first line somehow 14 times to have 14 different specific dates to count from in 14 different `p` elements by 14 IDs?
e.g.

```
<p class="date1" >show timer1</p>
<p class="date2" >show timer2</p>
<p class="..." >...</p>
<p class="date14" >show timer14</p>
```

Edit:
In addition I would like to know how I can have two additional `p`element outputs like

```
<p class="online_date0" >show text "This countdown is running right now"</p>
<p class="offline_date0 >show text "This countdown is not running at the moment</p>
```

... to have something like an indicator like "on air". Thanks!

**Edit Nov 1, 2017**

I don't get why this don't work in the specific if funktion:

```
if (distance < 0) {
clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("date" + index).className = "timerend";
    document.getElementById("outofdate" + index).className = "timerend";
    document.getElementById("date" + index).innerHTML = "00:00:00:00";
```

In the HTML document the date + index `p`s have a class which is removed when timerend is added. If I add a `+`before `=`in the first line after `clearInterval(x)` the old class stays, but the new class is added every second. I just want to add it one time of course. And if I don't put `+`before `=`in that line, the old class is removed of course.
Since I'm beginning to learn Js I want to understand what is happening here. What did I miss?
I just want to add a class to every `p` with indexed ids so it changes color when timer ends. It works, but it removes all other formats I put by the class those indexed `p`s have.

HTML

```
<p id="date0" class="dates"></p>
```

In CSS I put padding and so on in `.dates`. I've read about adding classes and keep originals, but can't understand a solution obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "multiply" your code, you could combine the use of an array and a function.

- In your array, you would define your 14 countDownDates.
- You would loop through this array with a for loop, for instance
- You would pass the current countDownDate information to a function that will handle the single countdown, just the way your code handles it now.

Here's an example :

```js
// defining countDownDates as an empty array : 
var countDownDates = [];

// adding any count down date to your array : 
countDownDates.push(new Date("Oct 24, 2017 10:49:50").getTime());
countDownDates.push(new Date("Oct 24, 2017 10:49:45").getTime());
countDownDates.push(new Date("Oct 28, 2017 10:49:45").getTime());
countDownDates.push(new Date("Oct 29, 2017 10:49:45").getTime());
countDownDates.push(new Date("Oct 30, 2017 10:49:45").getTime());
countDownDates.push(new Date("Nov 1, 2017 10:49:45").getTime());
countDownDates.push(new Date("Nov 12, 2017 10:49:45").getTime());
countDownDates.push(new Date("Nov 24, 2017 10:49:45").getTime());

// calling an init function that will build the HTML needed for every count down
init(countDownDates);

// looping through your array of countDownDates
for (var i=0;i<countDownDates.length;i++) {
 // calling the countdown function, pass it the array and the current version of i as parameters 
 countDown(countDownDates, i);
}
 
/* adds, to the document, a p element for each entry in the countDownDates array */
function init(countDownDates) {     
 var timersDiv = document.getElementById("timers");
 var dateElement;
 for (var i=0;i<countDownDates.length;i++) {      
  dateElement = document.createElement("p");
  dateElement.id = "date" + i;
  timersDiv.appendChild(dateElement);
 } 
}     

/* countDown function, your countDown handling code within a reusable function */
function countDown(countDownDates, index) {
 var x = setInterval(function() {
  var now, distance, days, hours, minutes, seconds, x;
  
  now = new Date().getTime();
  distance = countDownDates[index] - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) /
  (1000 * 60 * 60));
  minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);                            

  // Display days, hours, minutes and seconds in 2 digits if < 10
  if((days+"").length === 1){
   days = "0"+days;
  }
  if((hours+"").length === 1){
   hours = "0"+hours;
  }
  if((minutes+"").length === 1){
   minutes = "0"+minutes;
  }
  if((seconds+"").length === 1){
   seconds = "0"+seconds;
  }

  // Display the result in the element with id date0, date1, etc.
  document.getElementById("date" + index).innerHTML = days + ":" +
  hours + ":"
  + minutes + ":" + seconds + "";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
   clearInterval(x);
   document.getElementById("date" + index).innerHTML = "Ende!";
  }
 
 }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<!-- just an empty div we will add countDown elements into -->
<div id="timers">

</div>
```

Comment: This as well comes very close! Is there a way to make the timers come out individually? Or put the output of every timer in a specific `p`instead of putting all timers in a `<div>`?

Comment: Each timer is in a specific p element. All the p elements are in the 'timers' div, but they could be placed anywhere else.

Comment: I'm sorry for wrongly formulated question. I need to select those `p` elements individually via css. Maybe I'm too stupid but in your demo I just can select all `p`generally by `div#timers p {}`.
For my project I have 14 dates, every time two of them seperated by a day. I want to place the timers in order right beside its date.
e.g. Tuesday: 24.10.2017, 17:00 o'clock 00:00:00:00.

Comment: Edit-time-up:
Actually I AM to stupid! I just got it and I can select them individually via css. Sorry!
Well, what's left is that I have no idea how to drop the timers individually on my webpage. I guess I need to position them individually via `position: absolute`. Thank you very much for your help so far. I'd love to help you, too, If I ever could!

Comment: No worries. That's what we're here for :) Glad you figured out a way.

Comment: Sure! And, in case someone is looking for an answere to this specific case: Put in `<div id="timers"></div>` all specific timers can be positioned `absolute` easily by selecting them in the css via `p#date0 {}` (Js starts counting by 0 instead of 1) in the order of appearence in the script.
Thanks to both answeres – both are solutions I guess. In my case it's your answere and I AM really thankful for your help! All the best for you, RobertC.

Comment: Everything works fine except for one thing, so sorry I ask again, but: in the HTML file I want to add another css class to indivdual `p`, in fact `<p id="date4" class="end">`to set a prefix via`:before`. It works, but after 1 second (when the timer updates) it removes the class. How can I avoid that?

Comment: The way you coded it, the timer shouldn't be deleting a class from your p elements. It just changes the innerHTML of the p element. I can't see why this is happening. Can you edit your question and provide the updated code?

Comment: Sure! And I have another question: Is it possible to have another output in that script that puts another element like `e.g. <p id="online_date0"></p> and <p id="offline_data0"></p>` that indicates that the linked timer is running right now or not running at the moment additionally? You know, like "on air" thing. IF you'd like to help again.

Comment: 1 - When the timer ends, you are adding the className 'timerend'. And it stays there. I don't understand your previous comment about it being removed. 2 - You could add any other element you want. It happens in the init function. I won't do it for you, though. I strongly advise you to learn how to create DOM element and add them to the document. It's not complicated and you will be able to do it yourself. Here's an example of a documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: I figured a way to avoid that by using `span` right before the `p` so the color change is not affected anymore. Thanks for your help!
Thank you for the advise, for me this is very complicated in my mind, so thank you for the link! I hope I will achieve this by carefully reading. But for now making an indicator like asked for is unimaginable for me. So: Do I need anything else than the init function to achieve an indicator that shows that you are in the span of real time between two timers? Is this question more an approach or "timer with id=dateX running or not"? Thanks!

Comment: You will have to add your "indicator" element to the DOM (for instance in the init function) and then change its content in the countDown function (in the if (distance < 0) block. The same way you modify the innerHTML of your p element with "Ende". It's really not that hard. You can do it :)

Comment: Yes, I did it myself and it works! Thank you so much! Without your help I would have been lost.
I figured a quite simple way to create this indicator by adding the class `.outofdate` plus index to the specific `p` (not the countdown p's) and add the line `document.getElementById("outofdate" + index).className = "timerend";`after very much of reading. Thank you, my Master! :D

Comment: I've updated the question and added a code snippet below it, because I can't figure out why something doesn't work. Could you please have a look? What did I miss there? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an **demo** with 8 timers

- Refactor your logic to a method which accepts *element Node* and `countDownDate`
- Put `data-countDownDate` **millisecond value** in the element itself.
- Iterate the timers and initialize them.

```js
//var countDownDate = new Date("Oct 22, 2019 14:00:00").getTime();

[].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( ".dateTimer" ) ).forEach( function( element ){
  startTimer(element, Number(element.getAttribute( "data-countDownDate" )) );
});

function startTimer(element, countDownDate) {
  // Update the count down every 1 second
  //console.log( element );
  var x = setInterval(function() {

    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) /
      (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    if ((days + "").length === 1) {
      days = "0" + days;
    }
    if ((hours + "").length === 1) {
      hours = "0" + hours;
    }
    if ((minutes + "").length === 1) {
      minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    if ((seconds + "").length === 1) {
      seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }

    element.innerHTML = days + ":" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "";

    // If the count down is finished, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      element.innerHTML = "Ende!";
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<p class="dateTimer" data-countDownDate="1509823808052"></p>
<p class="dateTimer" data-countDownDate="1509823818052"></p>
<p class="dateTimer" data-countDownDate="1509823828052"></p>
<p class="dateTimer" data-countDownDate="1509823838052"></p>
<p class="dateTimer" data-countDownDate="1509823848052"></p>
<p class="dateTimer" data-countDownDate="1509823858052"></p>
<p class="dateTimer" data-countDownDate="1509823868052"></p>
<p class="dateTimer" data-countDownDate="1509823878052"></p>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand any JavaScript but in the approach it seems this could be the solution if there is a way to determine a specific date and time to an exact second. I need to set i.e. "month day, year hour:minute:second" so that the individual timer exactly shows how long until that specific moment.
Is there any way to alter the script so I could just type something like `<p class="dateTimer" data-countDownRate="Oct 31, 2017, 14:00:00"></p>`
so the output would be 06:20:49:24?

Comment: I would advise you to go with time-stamp millisecond value. Passing a string to Date constructor may come with caveats and also it includes extra parsing step.

Comment: I've read into time-stamp and it's very interesting – despite it is too complex for me as an absolute beginner. Thank you for your efforts in this case and advises. JavaScript is my next goal, before this I was even afraid of it because it seemed extremely difficult. Thank you!